# Accessing files in a Mac/network share on iOS?

Tags: file-sharing, afp

While on my home local network, I some times want to access images and plain-text files stored on an AFP network share.

But I have not found an app for iOS that allow me to do this. Can someone recommend a solution?

I do not want to use a service like Dropbox.

Comment: Can you flesh out the "want to access" part? As you have surmised, iOS does not have a file browser or even a unified concept that more than one app can read the same data (with exception of data that is classified by the system as a contact, picture in the camera roll and other limited sharing between sandboxes.)

Comment: I want to read the plain text files and view the images. Basics.

Comment: GoodReader and AFP or SFTP or WebDav. You'll need to download them to the device to view them though... Or what about VNC?

Answer (score 2):

I find [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/artist/good.iware-ltd./id289191291) to be the best. I consider it as my iOS Finder (by lack of better solutions, sadly).

It supports a wide range of protocols and web services such as AFP, WebDAV, FTP, SFTP, Dropbox, Box.net, Google Docs, SugarSync, IMAP and POP3. It used to support iCloud as well, but the feature is gone for stability and legal reasons.

It also makes it easy to upload an annotated version of a file at the same place you downloaded it.

Oh, and if you want to access all of your Mac files, SFTP is the way to go. Once you activated "Remote login" in the Sharing pane of System Preferences, you can connect via SFTP to your Mac with your username and password. As the server, use the address (something like `My-MacBook.local` given in the same Sharing pane (at least on the same local network).

Answer (score 0):

An app called [Files Connect](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/files-connect/id404324302?mt=8) is one of the best i've tried thus far. Check it out in the app store.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add some detail to this answer? A link to the app would be great, as would a description of its features and what makes it good. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone hitting this answer, this app linked here seems not in development any more and might not work any more